# The two pairs of sides of an inscribed quadrilateral meet at $G$ & $H$; angle bisectors at $G$ & $H$ meet at $K$. Prove $\angle GKH$ is a right angle.

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, quadrilateral

> Given that the two pairs of opposite sides of an inscribed quadrilateral meet when extended at $G$ and $H$ and the bisectors of the angles at $G$ and $H$ meet at K, prove that the $\angle GKH$ is a right angle.

Another proof that I'm completely stumped on. I'm thinking it has something to do with the angles of the quadrilateral and secants. Any hints/advice are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or contest, give the intended audience. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know (inscribed quads, angle bisectors, right angles) can get you going, and it keeps others from explaining things you already understand. ... In any case, the more you can show that you're personally invested in finding a solution, the more likely it is that others will become invested in helping you with the search.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for the advice. This is a textbook exercise that we've been challenged to figure out. I do know that the opposite angles of an inscribed quadrilateral are supplementary and thus that the exterior angle of an inscribed quadrilateral is congruent to the opposite interior angle. I don't know how that would help though. Secant-secant angles as well.

Answer (score 1):

What OP expressed in the comment does lead to a solution.

> Show by angle chasing that $2  \angle GKH = \angle GBH + \angle GDH = 180^\circ$.
> Hence $ \angle GKH = 90^\circ$.

If you get stuck, explain how you've tried to demonstrate this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let the intersection of $GE$ and $KH$ be point $P$. Let $\angle B$ and $\angle E$ be $\beta$ and $\alpha$ respectively.

$\angle GPK$ and $\angle KGP$ can be found by simple angle chasing. Now just add them and show that it's $90^{\circ}$.